# SDL Web8: How to PAUSE the publishing services?

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

I want to setup the PAUSE the publishing services for different Target. any one have idea how its will setup configuration?

Comment: Please add additional details on what is scenario and what you want to achieve with this operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is documented [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C22AE1FF-B653-4629-9AB4-8FF6718CC4DC).

It allows you to enable or disable a given CD Environment, and it will keep any publishing job you submit in the queue until the environment is re-enabled, at which point the publishing will resume.

Comment: I understand what you're asking for, for the simple reason that I know very well the customer you're working at. I have to agree with Hiren that you are not really phrasing your questions very well.

Comment: I have already shared the same link to enable / disable CD environment that you have shared however his response is he need something else which nobody knows other than him :D

Answer (score 1):

Since, the question is not very specific, giving a generic answer:

If requirement is to perform any deployments / patching on publisher then go to services (services.msc) and select the publisher service and pause the service.

> Please note, that pausing publisher will not allow any new publishing to go through for any of the target.

If requirement is to disable publishing by target then pausing publisher service is not the option. Instead disable content delivery environment. Refer: [article](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C22AE1FF-B653-4629-9AB4-8FF6718CC4DC) to disable / enable content delivery environments.

Comment: Thanks for the in Hiren, Current I PAUSE my publisher using services only.  I am looking for configuration setup in CME side.

Comment: @Sudhakar - If you share half baked information in the question, nobody here can help you. If you need help then share what is your scenario and what you have done.

Comment: scenario: I published my page WIP and WIP1 publishing targets. But I want to PAUSE WIP1 page publishing without service pause. I am looking for CME side. it`s it possible?

Comment: Please add these details to your question and also suggest what is the reason you want to pause publishing on WIP1?

Comment: it`s business requirement. some time authors don`t want publish page in specific target. that`s away looking for publishing targets PAUSE.

Comment: if authors don't want to publish to a specific target, then they shouldn't - it looks like there's a lot more to this question than what you're telling, you should probably expand more in your question above so that we can answer properly.